# Bootstrap accordion toggled from panel-heading + state indicators

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

Been trying to get it to work for 8 hours already by trying different CSS and jQuery solutions I was able to find plenty of, but none of these work with my needs.

I need the panel-heading to be the activating "button", so it would be easier to open the different sections.

None of the available methods have worked. They either don't do anything or activate certain classes on every tab of the accordion, but I only need the state change on the currently activated tab.

Down there's a jsfiddle without jQuery, but I think I've done the markup well with class="indicator" on fontawesome icon.

Sorry if this is a simple problem and I look dumb, but I really lack javascript experience.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
          Collapsible Group Item #1<i class="fa indicator fa-chevron-up"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
       First group.Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
          Collapsible Group Item #2<i class="fa indicator fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        Collapsible Group Item #3<i class="fa indicator fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </h4>
        </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading{background-color: #f5f5f5;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
.panel-default{border: none;}
.panel-group .panel{border-radius: 0;}
.panel{-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;border-left: 1px solid #f5f5f5;}
.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-top: none;}  
.panel-group .panel+.panel{margin-top: 0;}
.panel-title .fa{color:#87D37C;float: right;}
.panel-heading{border-radius: 0;cursor:pointer;}
```

_

http://jsfiddle.net/3tweewn1/

Comment: Are you asking how to toggle the chevron for the selected accordion? Sorry I'm confused by the question. . .

Comment: @gigelsmith I need the chevron-up if current accordion panel is open/active, so for example if has class .in. And I need chevron-down if panel is closed, so at least 2/3 of panels should always have chevron-down and if there's a opened panel, it should have chevron-up in the panel-title right hand side.

Sorry for the bad self expression. Hope that clarified. I would be extremely happy and would really appreciate if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font-awesome css file wasn't linking on your fiddle so I added a different cdn link and I added the code to display the font-awesome fonts on the actual fiddle so you can see it in action. http://jsfiddle.net/Lnws5fop/1/
I wasn't sure if you actually wanted the chevron right next to your panel-heading so I added "pull-right", you can remove if needed.

```
function toggleChevron(e) {
$(e.target)
    .prev('.panel-heading')
    .find("i.indicator")
    .toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
}
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```